# Excel Loop Column A action column B

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently looking for a code to improve my Dashboard. Actually, I need to know how to use a loop in a column X who will affect a column Y (cell on the same line).

To give you an example:

- Column A: I have all Production Order (no empty cell)
- Column B: Cost of goods Sold (Sometimes blank but doesn't matter)

I actually pull information from SAP so my Column B is not in "Currency". 
The action should be:
If A+i is not empty, then value of B+i becomes "Currency".
It's also for me to get a "generic" code that I could use with other things.

This is my current code...

```html
Sub LoopTest()
      ' Select cell A2, *first line of data*.
      Range("A2").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Style = "Currency"
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't use select, its terrible. See documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201706261411041591846

Comment: Something like this seems to work and is pretty easy

`Sub LoopTest()
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1

    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(row, 1))
        Cells(row, 2).Style = "Currency"
        row = row + 1
    Wend

End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another example, getting Last Row, in case your data contains any blank rows.

```
Sub UpdateColumns()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim r As Long

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

    For r = 2 To lastRow
        If wks.Cells(r, 1) <> "" Then
            wks.Cells(r, 2).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Sub calcColumnB()

    Dim strLength As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Rows.Count

        columnAContents = Cells(i, 1).Value

        strLength = Len(columnAContents)

        If strLength > 0 Then

            Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

        End If


    Next i

End Sub
```

Explanation--
What the above code does is for each cell in Column B, so long as content in column A is not empty, it sets the format to a currency with 2 decimal places

**EDIT:**

Did not need to loop

Comment: Thank you for your responsiveness !

Comment: The problem with this is that it unnecessarily processes all 1 million Excel rows in worksheet.

Comment: @GordonBell--good point! But the OP can always change `For i = 1 To Rows.Count` to `For i = 1 To #` (where he can specify explicitly, how many rows to process by changing the value of `#`

Answer (score 0):

I can see I was a little slower than the others, but if you want some more inspiration, heer is a super simple solution (as in easy to understand as well)

```
Sub FormatAsCurrency()
    'Dim and set row counter
    Dim r As Long
    r = 1

    'Loop all rows, until "A" is blank
    Do While (Cells(r, "A").Value <> "")
        'Format as currency, if not blank'
        If (Cells(r, "B").Value <> "") Then
            Cells(r, "B").Style = "Currency"
        End If

        'Increment row
        r = r + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Noceo, seems pretty easy to use and I will be able to change the action if I need something else

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simply one, that I tried to comment - but the formatting got messed up. It simply reads column 1 (A) for content. If column 1 (A) is not empty it updates column 2 (B) as a currency. Changing active cells makes VBA more complicated than it needs to be (in my opinion)

```
Sub LoopTest()
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1

    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(row, 1))
        Cells(row, 2).Style = "Currency"
        row = row + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```